# Error thrown. Cannot create references to/from string offsets

Tags: admin, login

I'm trying to access the /wp-admin on my old blog post, but when I try to get to the login page I'm getting an alert that reads as follows: "Error thrown. Cannot create references to/from string offsets"

I tried adding the patch described at [The website cannot display the page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/260277/the-website-cannot-display-the-page) , but am still getting the same error alert.

Basically I swapped out the line (on 770) that read:

```
$user = wp_signon( '', $secure_cookie );
```

and replaced it with these two lines (on 770 and 771):

```
$user = wp_signon( '', $secure_cookie );
$user = wp_signon( array(), $secure_cookie );
```

Is there anything else I could try?